# .NET Standard 1.5 XUnit console runner - How to run my unit tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, xunit, .net-standard, .net-standard-1.5

I have a test project configured with .NET Standard 1.5

IDE: Visual Studio 2017 Community

I have included `xunit` and `xunit.runner.console` but I cannot run the tests.
I tried `dotnet test` on the test project but I get the following error

> Could not find testhost.dll for source 'D:\Dev\Visual Studio
>   2017\CSharpSeven.NewFeatures\CSharpSeven.NewFeatures\CSharpSeven.Tests\bin\Debug\netstandard1.5\CSharpSeven.Tests.dll'.
>   Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package
>   "microsoft.testplatform.testhost".

My `.csproj` is the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.5</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost" Version="15.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.console" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CSharpSeven\CSharpSeven.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I've been struggling for quite sometime to get the tests running, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test projects needs to be runable applications. You need to target a specific runtime. For example:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

See this answer for more information

[Can't get XUnit tests to run with .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938879/cant-get-xunit-tests-to-run-with-net-core)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do a restore and build first ?

```
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

This should add any missing packages then you may run the tests.