# VSTS test task failed despite of success tests

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vstest

I get below error even after all the test passed under `VsTest` task.

```
2019-04-04T10:22:14.3913769Z Unable to find d:\a\r1\a\xxx\e2e\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\testhost.dll. Please publish your test project and retry.
2019-04-04T10:22:15.1564640Z Results File: d:\a\r1\a\TestResults\VssAdministrator_fv-az153_2019-04-04_10_22_13.trx
2019-04-04T10:22:15.1606430Z 
2019-04-04T10:22:15.1607111Z Test Run Aborted.
2019-04-04T10:22:15.1607372Z Total tests: Unknown. Passed: 6. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
2019-04-04T10:22:15.1607627Z Test execution time: 36.3008 Seconds
2019-04-04T10:22:15.3788506Z ##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
2019-04-04T10:22:15.3917110Z ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe' failed with exit code 1
2019-04-04T10:22:15.8355860Z ##[error]VsTest task failed
```

When I tried locally with below but no errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe C:\xxx\src\xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests.dll /logger:trx 2>error.txt
```

I tried [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7358) solution as well, but no luck.

**build.yaml**

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: "Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
      inputs: 
        contents: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests/**'
        targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: "dotnet e2e tests"
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/src/xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests
        zipAfterPublish: false

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: "Publish End-to-End Tests"
      inputs: 
        artifactName: e2e
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/src/xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests'
```

[image]

I noticed below in logs which has difference in paths (i.e. **Release pipeline** - `d:\a\r1\a\EstimationCore\e2e\xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests` and **Build pipeline -**`d:\a\1\a\src\xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1`

Full log :

```
Release pipeline - Download artifact - EstimationCore - e2e
2019-04-07T09:05:10.8843174Z Downloaded e2e/xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests/xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests.deps.json to d:\a\r1\a\EstimationCore\e2e\xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests\xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests.deps.json

Build pipeline - Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
Copying d:\a\1\s\src\xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests.deps.json to d:\a\1\a\src\xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests.deps.json
```

Comment: I think it's helpful if provides reasons when anyone add negative votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tests ran successfully after the below changes to the `build.yaml`. So as you can see the issue was with the folder paths

`task: CopyFiles@2` is not necessary

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: "dotnet e2e tests"
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/**/*.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests.csproj'
        arguments: --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        zipAfterPublish: false

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: "Publish End-to-End Tests"
      inputs: 
        artifactName: e2e
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Answer (score 2):

The task returned with: `Test Run Aborted.` Thus not all tests were executed. And this is the probable cause:

```
Unable to find d:\a\r1\a\xxx\e2e\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\testhost.dll. Please publish your test project and retry.
```

I'm happy this causes the test execution to fail :).

The error mentions you should publish your test project prior to running the tests to ensure all dependencies are copied into the output directory.

You haven't shared the rest of your workflow, but I'd hazard following the thing mentioned in the error makes a lot of sense.

Make sure all the paths are correct so that the right files are found. In build you take control over the paths through the `--output` in release each artefact is downloaded to a specific location based on the artefact name. This is to ensure releases with multiple artefacts don't overwrite each other's files accidentally.

Comment: I have added the `build.yaml` section where I am publishing the project. Am I missing anything there?

Comment: Other question I had was is `DotNetCoreCLI@2` and `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` does the same thing?

Comment: No DotNEtCoreCLI runs the `dotnet publish` command, which creates a deployable bundle of your project. PublishBuildArtefact only picks up the files you point it to and creates a storage container in the build system to store these files in and copies the files over.

Comment: PS why not just run `dotnet test`? What does the VsTest task give you over that?

Comment: Thanks for you clarification, actually in the intention is to run e2e test not part of build but after deploy the code into the environment. So with the above tasks in the `build.yaml` why it's still giving that error?

Comment: I noticed another mismatch between release and build pipeline logs.(Updated the question) Apparently it's relating to the error. Not sure what caused that difference.